# how to optimize a slow batch INSERT IGNORE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, optimization

Just finished rewriting many queries as batch queries - no more DB calls inside of foreach loops!

One of these new batch queries, and insert ignore into a pivot table, is taking 1-4 seconds each time. It is fairly large (~100 rows per call) and the table is also > 2 million rows.

This is the current bottleneck in my program. Should I consider something like locking the table (never done this before, but I have heard it is ... dangerous) or are there other options I should look at first.

As it is a pivot table, there is a unique key comprised of both the rows I am updating.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using indexes? Indexing the correct columns speeds things up immensely. If you are doing a lot of updating and inserting, sometimes it makes sense to disable indexes until finished, since re-indexing takes time. I don't understand how locking the table would help. Is this table in user by other users or applications? That would be the main reason locking would increase speed.

Comment: well, the call is part of a multi_curl callback function, so it is possible that one instance is trying to read from the table at the same time another instance is writing to it. I was thinking something like lock the table, drop indexes, do the insert, add the indexes, unlock the table. But, as you say, indexing takes time.